# Custom-styled radio button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For my WordPress website, I would like to create a custom-styled radio button with an overlay that replaces the default appearance when the radio button is checked. If the radio button is checked, the original should disappear (due to the different devices I otherwise cannot ensure that the blue original button is fully covered). My code is as follows but sadly doesn't work.

```css
/* Hide the default radio button */
input[type='radio']:checked {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom-styled button to overlay the checked radio button */
input[type='radio']:checked + .custom-radio-button {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #9b51e0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The HTML for the radio button is as follows:

```html
<div class="single-row">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="radio-899">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="menuradio">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="fist" checked="checked"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">fist</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="second"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">second</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="third"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">third</span></label>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pseudo element for this. Here, I used a `::before` element for the label (in this case the `span` tag after the input). If you have any question feel free to ask.

```css
/* Hide the default radio button */
input[type='radio']:checked {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom-styled button to overlay the checked radio button */
input[type='radio']:checked + span::before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    top: 1.5px;
    left: -1.5px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #9b51e0;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
}

/* positioning the label when input is hidden */
input[type='radio']:checked + span{
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-row">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="radio-899">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="menuradio">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="fist" checked="checked"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">first</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="second"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">second</span></label>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
                <label><input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="third"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">third</span></label>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I have found my problem: in the code, both the visibility of the selected radio button and the overlay are dependent on `input[type='radio']:checked`, so changing the opacity of one automatically affects the other. I sadly cannot change the html code of the contact form. How would you make the visibility of the custom overlay independent of the visibility of the selected radio button?

Comment: I understand the issue. You need to provide the Html, without seeing the markups it is not possible to provide a solution I think.

Comment: Hello, just added it. I am using contact form 7, i have to keep the "id=menuradio" for other code to work. I have to probably also change the html code, right? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: The codes you added are not the correct codes. It should contain the radio `input` and the `label` tags. I need to know how those are structured. If those codes are dynamic then you can inspect and copy from the browser or at least take a screenshot and update it here.

Comment: Does this work now? Sorry about the mess, I'm new to website development!

Comment: Yes, these are the correct codes. Checking it.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer with the adjustment for the new html.